# .net command-line compiler multiple projects

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, command-line

I need to build a batch file that runs on a directory and digs inside for suitable c# projects to compile. (and compile them of course).

I don't know the name of the projects inside the directory.

I can assume all project are in c# and written in VS2008 and above (if that helps).

Comment: Are those projects independnt? Ms Build can not resolve the correct build order from the proj file, you ned solution

Comment: Yes they are. I can't add them to one solution. Also, I think I mislead you, I need to create an .exe out of the projects, so probably I need to "build" and not "compile".

Comment: There are no dependencies between the projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setlocal
SET CMD= msbuild.exe 

for /R %%d in (*.csproj) do %CMD% %%d
endlocal
```

This will build each project into individual assemblies, with all default build properties for each project. You can specify additional properties, or an MSBuild config file to use.

Comment: Where do I put the path to the project? (For instance, it sits at c:\projects)

Comment: You can add a CD command to c:\projects, or put the batch file there.